# 2013 Nexus 7 frozen screen/stuck on language set up/boot loop

Tags: adb, nexus-7

I see similar questions here but none of them refer to being stuck on the language set up screen. I have tried to use ADB driver and Toolkit but I cannot seem to get my pc to recognize device half the time. plus it tells me to put my device on USB debugging mode and how can I do that when I cannot access my device? is there anyway out of this bullshit? honestly, ASUS needs to compensate/make good with the THOUSANDS of customers they have ripped off.

Comment: Are you trying to solve your problem, or are you just here to complain? If you want a solution, describe your problem fully. In what way are you "stuck"? What goes wrong? What have you tried to do with ADB?

Comment: I tried to comment but says I can't because of points/reputation. What I mean by stuck is the screen freezes when it reaches the light blue language set up screen. I have also downloaded and used the WUG tools and it seemed like it was remedied (Because I saw the screen say "Android apps loading" which I had never seen before.) But Again, right back to freezing on language set up. Everything seemed to go well according to the WUG and Nexus toolkit...but it's not.  Its a brand new device(never used)

Comment: If it's a brand-new device, why not just take it back to the shop?

Answer (score 0):

Your bootloader is most likely corrupted. I'd advice you to thus restore the stock rom. Download this tool on your computer http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/ from this link. Plug in your phone and run the programme. Download TWRP>unlock>back to stock and select softbricked/bootloop